# crontab -e does not save the cron for current user

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, cron

I am using `Ubuntu 20` under `AWS Ec2` instance. I have created a custom user other than the default user `ubuntu`. When I try to edit the cron file by `crontab -e` it opens the from file and shows the previously added crons. I want to edit the time/frequency of cron job to be executed.

I changed the time and saved it by `CTRL + o`. It saved successfully without any error. But when I exit by `CTRL + x` I see there is an error:

```
/var/spool/cron/: mkstemp: Permission denied
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.Zr6S9D/crontab
```

Actually long ago the command used to work and it was saving correctly. But after some period I don't know what happened to it.

When I edit the cron from root i.e. `sudo crontab -e` it opens and I can save anything in it. I don't want to execute cron from root because its creating too much file permission error time to time for a `Magento` Application

There are few things that I have tested.

- Server has the much space available
- Anything I edit in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<user_name>` is editable and I can save data in it when I open this in `nano`
- I tried deleting content of `/tmp` folder. No success.

Thanks.

Comment: sudo crontab -e does not use ROOT it uses your admin, crontab -e  uses your current user, that does not have to be the admin. sudo -i && crontab -e uses root. "its creating too much file permission error time to time for a Magento Application" no it does not; you are likely doing something wong ;-) and if that is an issue for you: why are you not using /etc/crontab? That one you can tell for each line what user to use for the command. The better approach would be to use a systemd  service.

Comment: Can you suggest me the code. What should I use?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?   So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 server system?  (Ubuntu uses *year.month* for *deb* based products & the *year* format for the *snap* only products; so 20 & 20.04 are different products)

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about that. I used Ubuntu 20 as symbolic means.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 & Ubuntu 20.04 LTS are different products, because of the *confinement* used in 20, added complications exist (even if 20 is built from the 20.04 base).  Ubuntu Core 20 is quick to *spin* up in cloud environments so has advantages (*a smaller system as less complex than the 20.04 product*).